# Select one piece of data from every day at a specific hour MySQL

Tags: mysql

My database has data imputed every 1 minute and is stored in the format `2020-04-05 16:20:04` under a column called `timestamp`.

I need a MySQL query to select data from every day at a specific hour (the second does not matter), for for example I want to get the data from 16:00 of every day from the past 30 days.

It currently, just grabs the data from the past 30 days and then the PHP application sorts it, however, this is causing very slow loading time, hence wanting to only select the wanted data from the database.

[Example of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeKYU.jpg)

Comment: You need to provide some example data and at least a query that you have attempted [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63025269/edit) to make it more interesting. At the moment, your question is almost certainly be flagged as "need more details/clarity" and closed. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following sql:

```
select
       d.timestamp, hour(d.timestamp)
from
     demo1 d
where
      DATEDIFF(NOW(), d.timestamp) < 30 and hour(d.timestamp) = 16;
```

The create sql is as following:

```
CREATE TABLE `demo1` (
        `id` int(11) not null auto_increment primary key,
        `serverid` int(11) not null,
        `timestamp` datetime not null,
        KEY `idx_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
    ) engine = InnoDB;

insert into `demo1` (serverid, timestamp)
VALUES (1, "2020-07-05 16:20:04"),
       (2, "2020-07-06 17:20:04"),
       (3, "2020-07-07 16:40:04"),
       (4, "2020-07-08 08:20:04"),
       (5, "2020-07-05 15:20:04"),
       (5, "2020-07-05 16:59:04"),
       (5, "2020-06-04 16:59:04");
```

Answer (score 0):

Zhiyong's response will work, but wont perform well.  You need to figure out a way to get the query to use indexes.

You can add a simple index on timestamp and run the query this way:

```
SELECT
       d.timestamp, d.*
FROM demo1 d
WHERE 1
 AND d.timestamp > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
 AND hour(d.timestamp) = 16;
```

In MySQL 5.7 and up, you can created a generated column (also called calculated column) top store the hour of the timestamp in a separate column.  You can then index this column, perhaps as a composite index of hour + timestamp, so that the query above will perform really quickly.

```
ALTER TABLE demo1
ADD COLUMN  hour1 tinyint GENERATED ALWAYS AS (HOUR(timestamp)) STORED,
ADD KEY (hour1, timestamp);
```

The result query would be:

```
SELECT
       d.timestamp, d.*
FROM demo1 d
WHERE 1
 AND d.timestamp > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
 AND hour1 = 16;
```

More info on that here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/generated-column-index-optimizations.html